Are there large-range variable capacitors?
I want to use a variable non-polarized capacitor which can vary between 10 pF to 1 μF, or at least up to 100 nF.
I can only find trimming caps which can only go up to 100 pF.
Am I looking for something that does not exist?

Emulate the large capacitor using either

With a 50 micron gap filled with high dielectric material, you're looking at something like a square meter of plate area to get to 1 uF, and that is a pretty close gap for something that has to be able to move.  Depending on how large the item can be and how many times it has to be able to change before you wear through the dielectric and short it out, this may or may not even be possible.  Normally you would try to design out the need for such a large variable capacitor using other components.

Assuming you don't want a trivial "no" answer: this seems to be an X-Y problem.  Please ask about your underlying problem X, not the question about your proposed solution Y (extremely large variable capacitor) to problem X (something that could use an extremely large variable capacitor).

Capacitor decade box is a thing.

What is the excitation that will be applied to this variable capacitor, specifically: the maximum voltage amplitude, waveshape, and frequency.  What is the application, eg: RC timer, signal filter, part of a resonant tank, energy storage, or something else?


Are there large-range variable capacitors?

If I need to be able to adjust capacitance that is somewhat larger than normal trimmers, I use a hexadecimal switch and 4 fixed value capacitors. So, if you need to vary capacitance up to 100 nF I'd use a 47 nF for the "8" position on the switch, a 27 nF on the "4" position on the switch, a 15 nF on the "2" position and a 7n5 on the "1" position. Then if I wanted to go deeper and fill in the gaps (if there were any) I'd employ a secondary hexadecimal switch using a much smaller range of capacitors.
Keep getting lower and lower until you can add a trimmer.
Hexadecimal switch (plenty to choose from and not pricey either): -


This is the closest to what I was asking for.

The variable capacitor you want is in a filter/oscillator, right? Please edit the question to make that clear.
Emulate the large capacitor using a small one and an op-amp based impedance multiplier with gain <1, ie. so that the output capacitive conductance is much higher than the conductance of the variable capacitor you’re using.
You can also use a variable inductor and a gyrator.
You can also use a bunch of capacitors of various values, some CMOS switches, and an MCU to connect them in parallel/series to obtain the desired output capacitance. It won’t take many capacitors to get very good resolution - better than that of a 10-turn potentiometer. The capacitors also don’t need to have tight tolerances, just appropriately low voltage coefficient of capacitance. The MCU will measure all of them before connecting them to the load in a selected parallel/serial configuration. As long as capacitors can be disconnected from the load and re-measured periodically, there will be no thermal drift. The MCU can also characterize thermal drift of each capacitor over time.
You can also use a fast MCU, a fast 16-18bit ADCx2 and a DAC, and digitally control a source-measure unit that can then emulate any impedance you need. The SMU would be self-made, not an off-the #helf unit due to bandwidth requirements and the requirement for emulating non-resistive impedance.

This was a yes or no question. So you are basically saying "no there are no such capacitors manufactured".

@pnatk No practical way to make a mechanical continuously variable capacitor that spans 4 or 5 decades. As Kuba states, you can synthesize something or make a decade capacitor box. However, the wiring capacitance will make the low-pF range inaccurate unless you spend time trimming things. Since you don't state what you want this for, the topology will be left up to you.

@pnatk If you put it into a box and it works as a capacitor, it is a capacitor. Why do you care that the capacitor is made from some mechanical parts? Pray tell how you’d adjust this wide range mechanical capacitor. Assume I gave you one, with 240 degree rotation for full range logarithmic sweep. You’ll need some expensive servoing to tune that capacitor to desired value. You don’t actually want a passive capacitor at all. Be careful what you wish for - assume a yes answer and see what swamp you got yourself into. That capacitor will also drift nicely. They don’t make them for a good reason.

Could probably do 10:1 or a bit better with an MOS varactor. That's a fair bit more than is practical with mechanical variables. Of course that is small-signal capacitance. One really wonders why OP thinks such a thing would be useful.
